# How to get the commit hash (ID) from specific commit count?

Tags: git

[image]

Each time we committed, that consider as a count. You can check your current commit count by running this command:

`git log --pretty=format:'' | wc -l`

---

## 100th

Let's assume, I want to get the commit-id of my `100th` commits.

Is there a way to get the commit id base on that count?

Comment: what do you mean by commit count?

Comment: Each time we committed, that consider as a count. You can check your current commit count by running this : `git log --pretty=format:'' | wc -l
`

Comment: Which commit do you want the id for?

Comment: @Code-Apprentice `100` th, as I stated in the OP.

Comment: @cyber8200 When I read your OP, that isn't entirely clear. I suggest you edit to make that more clear.

Comment: Do you mean that the current `HEAD` is the 1st commit, and its 99th ancestor is the 100th commit, or do you mean that the very first commit in the repo is the 1st commit, and all of its 99th descendants are each considered a 100th commit?

Comment: @ChristofferHammarström : If you did your first commit , that's 1. After a while, you will make 100 commits, that's `100th`, if someone come back to you to relook into your commit `#65`. What would that be ? 

That is what I am after - right now.

Comment: @cyber8200: OK, because everyone seems to be answering the other way around.

Comment: @ChristofferHammarström, yep. I will make a diagram. I have no idea why people think like that. I think only `Daniel` answer that way. I think Rakmo on the right track.

Comment: @ChristofferHammarström I updated my OP with picture to make it cleaer.

Comment: I think they think that because your request is very unusual. People normally don't track commit counts, except as in number of parents back. Usually you don't need to know the number of commits from the root. It would be interesting to hear what you are going to use this for.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
git log -1 --skip=n
```

will skip the first n-commits, and just show 1 commit

To just get the ID:

```
git log -1 --skip=n --pretty=format:"%h" --no-patch
```

Where in your case **n=100**

Comment: What are you talking about ? Is this even relevant ?

Comment: I need to get the commit id of my `100th` commit.

Comment: @cyber8200 Then yes, this is relevant. Just replace `n` with `100`. Or maybe `99`.

Comment: Ok, I will try that again then.

Comment: I have added further to get "just the Hash"

Comment: I've tried that command - nothing is printing : https://i.imgur.com/DT6Qpms.png

Comment: Replace n with 100: 

git log -1 --skip=100 --pretty=format:"%h" --no-patch

Comment: I am not sure of your Git history, but does it go back to count 2323 also? This should work until your first commit.

Comment: My real current commit `2236`, so `2323` definitely there.

Comment: Dude.. See what you are saying. Your current commit count is less than that you are searching for :)

Comment: @Rakmo : You're right, your answer is perfect then. :)

Answer (score 1):

You can also do `git show HEAD~n --format=oneline` to just get the one commit.

Comment: I need to get the commit id of my `17th` commit. Let's say `n=17`

Comment: oh ok. that's what I need. I didn't know n was for the number.

Comment: I got this error running your suggestion `⚡️  git show HEAD^2323 --format=oneline                                                                 
fatal: ambiguous argument 'HEAD^2323': unknown revision or path not in the working tree.                            
Use '--' to separate paths from revisions, like this:                                                               
'git <command> [<revision>...] -- [<file>...]'                                                                       `

Comment: @cyber8200 oops try `~` instead of `^`.

Comment: Ok, will try again now base on your updated answer.

Comment: `git show HEAD~2323 --format=oneline                                                                 
fatal: ambiguous argument 'HEAD~2323': unknown revision or path not in the working tree.                            
Use '--' to separate paths from revisions, like this:                                                               
'git <command> [<revision>...] -- [<file>...]' ` <--- now get this

Comment: Are you counting from top to bottom?

Comment: @cyber8200 thats the way git works - from most recent to the past.

Comment: Ok, will leave it then. BTW, your answer is backward what I asked.

Comment: @cyber8200 you could do some math and calculate it yourself... subtraction is your friend.

Answer (score 1):

You've drawn your commits as being all in a nice neat straight line.

This *does* sometimes happen, but in most real repositories, there are sections of commits that *are not* in a nice neat straight line:

```
...--A--B--D---------H--I--J   <-- newest
         \          /
          C--E--F--G
```

Let's say we want commit `I`.  This is easy to find: it's one step back from commit `J`.  Using:

```
git rev-parse newest~1
```

will find commit `J`.  Similarly, to find commit `H`, we can go back two steps:

```
git rev-parse newest~2
```

will print the hash ID of commit `H`.

But commit `G` is two steps *back*, then one step *down-and-back*.  Commit `D` is three steps back in a straight line.  This happens because commit `H` is a *merge commit*.

Assuming commit `D` is the *first* parent of commit `H`, writing:

```
git rev-parse newest~3
```

will find its hash ID.  Git will step back three times, along the first-parent line.  There's only one parent of `J` and only one of `I` so the first parent is the only parent, but at `H`, the first-parent specifically chooses `D` and not `G`.

If you use `git log` or `git rev-list`, both of these must display the commits linearly.  The method they use to do this is rather tricky, and the order that commits show up, in this output, is affected by command-line options: `--author-date-order`, `--topo-order`, and so on.

If you're satisified with the order that `git rev-list` (or `git log`) uses on its own, use [Rakmo's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/61803392/1256452).  (Remember that `git log` and `git rev-list` work *backwards*, from the newest towards the oldest.  You can have them reverse their output with `--reverse` but this interacts weirdly with `--skip`.  You might want to just get a complete list of commits, reverse it, and pick the n'th line of that.)

If you would like to traverse first-parents only, and want to count from the *end*—that is, `newest` names the newest, `newest~1` names the commit one step back, and so on—use [Daniel A. White's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/61803409/1256452) or some variant of it.

For more complex answers to what turns out to be a complex question (if you aren't satisfied with Git's default linearization, that is), you'll need to refine the question.

Comment: Your explaining is precisely perfect . Thank-you.